# dl.google.com:443 failed to respond

Tags: android, gradle

Getting error

> Cause: dl.google.com:443 failed to respond

Below is the `build.gradle` file code

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}}allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}}task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

and

```
dependencies { implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0' testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' }
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? If not, should you be?

Comment: My another gradle file code

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional information

Answer (score 7):

edit **[user]/.gradle/gradle.properties** file ( e.g.
`/home/jim/.gradle/gradle.properties` or
`C:\users\jim\.gradle\gradle.properties` ) , config proxy, like this

```
# https proxy settings.  
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=1080
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 4):

I am an android developer from China, I met the same problem as you.
This problem is mostly because I am behind a proxy. So there are two steps that may help you.

1. File->Settings->Appearance&Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy

   Then select No proxy option
2. Locate `gradle.properties` file in `.gradle` directory (this directory is generally in The User directory) and edit it. Delete every line about HTTP Proxy. Mine is like this

   ```
   systemProp.https.proxyPort=1080
   systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
   systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
   systemProp.http.proxyPort=1080
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' }
```

in your gradle. hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Psiphon go to setting-->Http proxy and enter the Http proxy number of Psiphon-->Log-->Http proxy is running on localhost ....(number) , and then enter port number sth like 80 , and let android studio download thigs that wants.

Answer (score 0):

I have to delete .AndroidStudio3.x, redo the proxy settings then problems gone.